# Netty client do not send data

Tags: java, client-server, netty

I'm trying to develop a rest API client-server. My client is in Java with Netty and my server using golang.
Currently, I get a really weird problem, my client do not send the POST request data to the server in some conditions.

Here are the details:

*- Part of my client code:*

**Bootstrap**

```
      Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap()
              .group(group)
              .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
              .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
              .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)            
              .remoteAddress(Host, Port)
              .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                  @Override
                  protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                      ch.pipeline()
                              .addLast(new HttpClientCodec())
                              .addLast(new ClientHandler());
                  }
              });
      return b.connect().syncUninterruptibly().channel();
```

**Send Request**

```
            if (channel.isActive() && channel.isWritable()) {
                FullHttpRequest postRequest = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(
                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        uri);
                postRequest.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.HOST, Host + ":" + Port);
                postRequest.headers().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                postRequest.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);
                postRequest.content().writeBytes(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(postRequest);
                channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                        logger.info("Send completed!");
                    }
                });
```

*- Some info I have from debugging*

- Things work fine when I run the code in IntelliJ, this only happens
  when building it into jar file and run from the jar file.
- As I capture package with wireshark, TCP handshake succeeds, but
  there is no POST data sent.
- I think this somehow related to the data length if the request data
  length is less than 150 bytes then everything is fine.
- Netty also reports that the sent operation complete (as "send completed"
  shows in my log file).

Is there anyone here encounter the same problems before or has any idea about how to fix this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where netty would swallow the exception when using the asynchronus way, even completing the future with "Send completed!". But my wireshark logs never showed more than the SYN->SYN,ACK->ACK flow.

My code was as followed:

```
ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(new byte[10]);
            channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                    logger.info("Send completed!");
                }
            });
```

After I changed my code to be synchron like so:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(new byte[10]).sync();
```

I finally discovered that there was infact an error:

*[11:58:50] [WARN] An exception was thrown by xx.xxxx.xxxxx.ProxyClient.operationComplete()
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: [B (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion)*

Turns out I need to `writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[10]))` wrap my array.

So what I learned is that the asynchronus way will happly tell you it was succesfull!

But wait, I then discovered that it probabbly did not swallow any exception, it was just me not checking for it!

```
                @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if(!future.isSuccess()){
                    logger.info(future.cause());
                }
            }
```

So if you change your future listener to check for `isSuccess()` and print the cause, it will show you the same error.

I hope that if you inspect your future, maybe you can discover the cause too.